# Why does SF retrieves an extra Id column when querying on standard objects?

Tags: apex, soql, query, fields, standard-objects

I'm doing the following query via Apex in my Org with standard objects:

```
SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE (Id IN ('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') ) AND Account.UUID__c = '112b5074-e280-4799-8c89-8c1d89caa14c' LIMIT 10000
```

The result of this query via Apex is the following:

```
Case:{Id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, AccountId=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY}
```

I'm not expecting the extra column `AccountId`, why I'm receiving it?

Extra information; If I do the query via API the results are the expected:

```json
{
   "totalSize":1,
   "done":true,
   "records":[
      {
         "attributes":{
            "type":"Case",
            "url":"/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/Case/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
         },
         "Id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I agree that this is happening (tested on a Summer '22 org) with something as trivial as `SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Account.Name = 'xyz'` and suspect it is leakage because of the reference to an account field in the WHERE clause. It doesn't appear in the result if you don't reference `Account` in the WHERE clause (even if you do reference `AccountId`).

Comment: Salesforce includes some automatic fields depending on the query and context. In particular, Visualforce causes things like RecordTypeId and CurrencyIsoCode to also appear in the results, even if you don't ask for them. This is to ensure that Visualforce has all the data it needs to render the page. I've linked a previous question that has similar language.

Comment: @sfdcfox, it's similar but not the same. It's not like the AccountId is always added, just when you reference an Account related object field, and as Nagendra said, this field does NOT appear in the actual SObject, just in the debug.

Comment: @PhilW The answer is still fairly relevant, though. The query you input isn't the query that Salesforce necessarily builds. There's no documentation on it, and this logic has been around for so long I doubt there's anyone working at salesforce.com that would even know.

Comment: @sfdcfox, somewhat relevant but not the whole story because the "artefacts" are only visible via debug, not usable in apex code. I think Nagendra's answer here adds a bit of value from that perspective.

Answer (score 2):

You might have printed in `System.debug` and you may be able to see this value.

But it is not available for use. If you try to use this in Apex code.
You will receive an error `Error on line 3, column 1: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Case.AccountId`

**Just a theory** : As its only available in debug statements, any lookup added in where clause is printed in debug just for information purpose.

Comment: What you say is true, though there's no real explanation as to **why** it is there in the debug. We know **when** it happens, just not **why**. One for a Salesforce product/development person to answer :)

Comment: Yes, just a theory from my side. Someone from Salesforce team needs to answer.